# Помогите вывести URL по ID фотки в галереи

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, вывод

Код выводит URL ***последней*** фотки из галереи поста с товаром WooCommerce.

```
$product_id = get_queried_object_id();
$product = new WC_product($product_id);
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id )
  {
    echo $Original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
  }
```

Как задать, чтобы можно было вывести фотку по ID фотки в галереи? Например всего в галереи две фотки, а нужно вывести не последнюю, а первую?
Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: $arrayl_image_url[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); - создаете массив юрл

затем выводите тот, что нужен

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить изображения товара с помощью методов `get_gallery_image_ids` и `get_image_id`. В `get_gallery_image_ids` будет массив айдишников, а в `get_image_id` просто айдишник.

```
global $product;
$gallery = $product->get_gallery_image_ids(); // Получить все картинки из галлереи
$thumb   = $product->get_image_id(); // Получить изображение товара (главное)
```

Выводить предпочительнее с помощью ф-ции `wp_get_attachment_image`, но если вам нужно просто получить ссылку, то с помощью `wp_get_attachment_image_url`:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'shop_catalog' ); // Вывести изображение
echo sprintf( '<img src="%">, wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'shop_catalog' ) ); // Вывести изображение
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите вывести фотку по ID (под ID я так понимаю, вы имеете ввиду идентификатор изображения, они идут в строку через запятую) Вы можете использовать этот простой код

обязательно в начале функции вставить эту строку:
global $wpdb;
Эта строка подключает базу данных Wordpress

```html
<?php
global $wpdb;

$table_posts = $wpdb->prefix."posts"; // таблица базы данных постов (Здесь хранятся ссылки на изображения)

$id_picture = 100; // Идентификатор картинки, для примера поставил 100

$sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_posts where ID = '$id_picture'");
foreach($sql as $sql_new)
{
    $image_id = $sql_new->ID; // Идентификатор картинки
    $image_url = $sql_new->guid; // Ссылка (url) картинки              
}

?>
```

Comment: И зачем вы это написали? Если айдишники у товара уже есть и они закешированы, а вы предлагаете делать еще 1 запрос. Вредный совет